# Android-Based Projector Remote Controller

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, infrared, remote-control

I am planning to create an android application which is a remote control for projector. The android application should do the following:

- Control the Focus Ring of the projector using Stepper Motor.
- Change the angular elevation of the projector.
- Position the projector up and down using a Linear Actuator.
- Clone the original IR remote control of the projector.

I will be using Arduino Mega for this project and Blutooth Module for android device - Arduino Mega Communication.

1. I have found out that it is possible to clone the protocol of IR remote control using 3 pin IR Receiver. But most of the examples online are done on TV. Some used IR remote control to turn on LED's. I just want to ask if RC's of projectors are just similar in to TV's or any audio system. Is it possible to decode their protocol? Do I need to use some library which does not come with arduino sdk?
2. Since I will be using a stepper motor to rotate a focus ring, what would be the best way to detect if the focus ring can no longer be rotated or has reached its limit so that my stepper motor will not force the ring to rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, yes,  use any remote control learning sketch with an appropriate ir receiver, with the original remote. Many projectors use standard tv type remote modulation. Epson projectors use NEC for example.

2. If the ring only has a fixed single turn, limit switches would work. If it rotates around multiple times, it would be harder.

Comment: I was thinking of some mechanism that would stop my stepper motor from rotating when the ring can no longer move. That "Limit Switch" gave me an idea. Thanks!